# How can I programmatically 'set' all parameters of a Dialog, such as 'dialog title', 'ok text', etc., without having string literals as parameters?

Tags: java, dialog, actionlistener, codenameone, anonymous-class

This is more of a programming style-related question rather than a functionality-related question.

All examples I see for creating a CodenameOne dialog box appear something like this:

```
.
.
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
.
.
// Create a button
Button myButton = new Button("Click Me");

// Create an action listener for the button
myButton.addActionListener((e) -> Dialog.show("Dialog title", "Dialog text", "OK", null));
.
.
.
```

The above `Dialog.show()` command has 4 parameters inside. However, if possible,  I wish to remove them, and 'set' them, as per the style below:

```
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog();       // Empty parameter list
myDialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");    // 1st parameter
myDialog.set???   // How can I 'set' "Dialog text" (2nd parameter) like I just did with Dialog Title?
myDialog.set???   // How can I 'set' "OK" (3rd parameter) like I just did with Dialog Title?
myDialog.set???   // How can I 'set' null (4th parameter) like I just did with Dialog Title?

// ...and then just do something like ...

myButton.addActionListener((e) -> myDialog.show());   // empty parameter list
```

How can I 'set' the dialog text, the ok button text, etc. in the same manner that I could use `dialog.setTitle()`? Is there a corresponding setter for each of those other parameters?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm probably missing something in your question, but couldn't you replace the hard-coded strings in Dialog.show with String variables? Just make sure that for the buttons, if you don't want the ok or cancel button the variable points to null. Modify the strings as you want prior to invoking Dialog.show.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The question has been edited to clarify. Yes, I could do what you suggested and it would work. But that's not exactly what was asked. Thanks.

Comment: How about sub-classing Dialog and adding more static helper methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no setters for the parameters used in `show (String title, String text, String okText, String cancelText)` except for `setTitle()`. You can search in the [official docs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Dialog.html), except for the method `show`, there is no other references to `text`, `okText` or `cancelText`. You must put all the parameters for that overload of the method `show`, that's how the API is made.

If you want to do extra work to get more setters, you could do like @James H suggested (I don't know why I didn't think of that at first): create a derived class. I'm pretty sure that the parameters of `show ()` don't have any corresponding field, so in the derived class (e.g. `OkCancelDialog`) you could add the fields `text`, `okText` and `cancelText`, create a default constructor and a parameterized constructor and the getters/setters for those fields, plus a `show` method that uses those fields. Then you just nees to change `Dialog` with `OkCancelDialog`.

```
public class OkCancelDialog extends Dialog {
    private String text=null, okText=null, cancelText=null;

    public OkCancelDialog (String text, String okText, String cancelText){
        super ();
        this.text = text;
        this.okText = okText;
        this.cancelText = cancelText;
    }

    public void setText (String text) { this.text = text; }
    public void setOkText (String okText) { this.okText = okText; }
    public void setCancelText (String cancelText) {this.cancelText = cancelText; } 

    public boolean show () { 
        return super.show (this.title, this.text, this.okText, this.cancelText); 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. BTW, I think the OP was asking if there is a general alternative to passing parameters. For example, like "named arguments" in PL/SQL or VBA.

Comment: @George I based my answer on the example he gave, `myDialog.setTitle ("Dialog Title")`, as the way to "set", which is the java way with a setter or with a constructor. If the OP said "in the same way as SQL" instead of "in the same manner that I could use `dialog.setTitle ()`", then my answer would be out of context...

Comment: Thank you Olipro007 !! This explanation and code example are excellent, and exactly what I was looking for. It's more to help increase my understanding of the inside workings of Java than to solve a particular programming task. Perhaps I was not sure how best to phrase my question using a Java and OOP terminology, but you got the point. Brilliant!

Comment: @Dan I'm glad this edit helped you. Also thanks to James H, his comment made me realize a quite simple solution that I completely forgot about. If this fixed your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi. I'm new on here. Not sure how to 'accept' the answer. I only see 'share', 'edit', and 'add comment' links.

Comment: @Dan You accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the vote counter of the answer. It becomes green when the answer is accepted. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is the help page for that.

Answer (score 1):

For **existing** functions or methods, like `Dialog.show()`, you cannot do this in java.

A construct like you want to have is possible in other languages, but it is not part of java.

Reference about method invocation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

You must always use a **list** of parameters, like `(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Comment: Thanks. Note that this is a CodenameOne question.
Dialog comes from:
`com.codename1.ui.Dialog`

Not completely accurate, as:

`Dialog myDialog = new Dialog();`
`myDialog.setTitle("Dialog Title")`
`myButton.addActionListener((e) -> myDialog.show());`
    
... produces a dialog box with the title.

Answer (score 1):

`show` is a static helper method inspired in part by `JOptionPane` from Swing. The core functionality of a `Dialog` is as a `Form`/`Container`.

E.g.:

```
Dialog dlg = new Dialog("My Dialog");
dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
dlg.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new SpanLabel("This is the body of the dialog, I can add anything I want here..."));
dlg.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Button(new Command("OK"));
```

Notice that using a `Command` implicitly disposes the `Dialog` but you can write a listener that calls `dispose()` on `dlg`.

You can also use one of the static `show` method variants that accepts a `Container` as the body of the `Dialog`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into using that technique to try to solve my issue.